# What command compares two directories recursively and validates that they are exact mirror images (if possible)?

Tags: terminal, copy-paste, verify

I'm moving files from pCloud to Google Drive and when using Finder the copy process aborts sometimes due to invisible files and what not.

So i'm using `cp -r` command in Terminal (Google Drive's top level shared drives need to be created in the Drive Admin tool so that part is a manual process).

the pCloud driver keeps crashing mid-operation, so i have to restarted the driver and start from where i left off by reissuing the command.

wondering if there's a command in macOS terminal that will confirm that I have mirror copies in Google Drive of the pCloud repository, given all the failed attempts due to invisible files and driver crashes.

Comment: Might be easier to use rsync which is able to restart/continue if it aborts for whatever reason.

Comment: thanks. copy is smart enough to pick up where it crashed last time, it starts working on the next uncopied folder straight away. I'll check out rsync for sure for future use, thanks.

Comment: Are you using a non-standard version of  `cp`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to this is rsync. Not just to do the copy as @nohillside suggests but it can be setup to do just a verification.

Normally I would say you need to get a newer version of rsync than macOS provides as the macOS one does not keep extended attributes but as cloud synchronizers don't either then that will not matter.

You can run rsync to do a dry-run, that is not to copy any files but just report the differences. The command is

```
rsync --dry-run -av pcloud-dir/ gdrive-dir/
```

A copy can be done by removing --dry-run
This has another advantage over Finder in that if the copy is interrupted then you can just repeat the same command and it will not recopy the files already done.

Comment: `rsync --dry-run -av pcloud-dir gdrive-dir` will sync `pcloud-dir` *into* `gdrive-dir`, which is to say it'll create the directory `gdrive-dir/pcloud-dir` and copy files under that. If you want it to sync `pcloud-dir` *with* `gdrive-dir` (i.e. with sync the directories themselves, not create a subdirectory), you need to add a `/` to the end of the source path: `rsync --dry-run -av pcloud-dir/ gdrive-dir`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks I always end up doing a dry-run to sort directories out

Comment: These days I prefer `-i` to `-v` because it gives an indication of _what_ is different (permissions, timestamp, content). So I would use: `rsync -ain [dir1] [dir2]`

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @mmmmmm ; rsync is the better choice over cp

An alternative to rsync to determine

> if there's a command in macOS terminal that will confirm that I have
> mirror copies in Google Drive of the pCloud repository

one can use the **diff** command.
**diff** can provide a comparison of two directories and will return what exists only in one folder or another, or nothing at all if they are the same.

```
diff -r /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2
```

And, if @wide_eyed_pupil you are intent on sticking with **cp**, you can add some arguments to not copy files already in the destination and to preserve attributes and permissions.
For example:

```
cp -nRav
```

have a look at `man cp` to see what all the arguments do.

Also, of note from the man page..

> COMPATIBILITY
> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly
> discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic
> links, or fifo's.

(use **-R** instead)